# Sendmail stopped sending mails (unable to qualify my own domain name (Centos) -- using short name)

Tags: centos, hostname, sendmail

All mails suddenly stopped sending, here is the maillog:

```
Jan 26 17:02:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: My unqualified host name (Centos) unknown; sleeping for retry
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: unable to qualify my own domain name (Centos) -- using short name
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPA003544: Authentication-Warning: Centos: apache set sender to noreply@mydomain.com using -f
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPA003544: from=noreply@mydomain.com, size=470, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=, relay=apache@localhost
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPA003544: to=myaddress@myhost.com, ctladdr=noreply@mydomain.com (48/48), delay=00:01:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30470, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPA003544: t0QG2KPB003544: DSN: Service unavailable
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3545]: t0QG3K4Q003545: Centos [127.0.0.1] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPB003544: to=noreply@mydomain.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31494, relay=[127.0.0.1], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPB003544: t0QG2KPC003544: return to sender: Service unavailable
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPC003544: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32518, relay=[127.0.0.1], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPB003544: Losing ./qft0QG2KPB003544: savemail panic
Jan 26 17:03:20 vm2745 sendmail[3544]: t0QG2KPB003544: SYSERR(apache): savemail: cannot save rejected email anywhere
```

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       Centos localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

hosts.allow:

```
ALL : 127.0.0.1, 212.226.x.x, 10.10.10. 
sendmail : ALL
sendmail : localhost
popa3d : ALL
```

hosts.deny:

```
ALL:ALL
```

/etc/mail/access:

```
Connect:localhost.localdomain       RELAY
Connect:localhost           RELAY
Connect:127.0.0.1           RELAY
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed `Centos` from *hosts* and added this line:

`mydomain.com.ip.address mydomain.com`

Now it works.